# How do I provide byte value specifically to a class having m1(byte) and m1(int) signatures

Tags: java, overloading

```
public class HelloWorld
{ 
   public void m1(int i) 
   { 
      System.out.println("int-arg"); 
   } 
   public void m1(byte j) 
   { 
      System.out.println("byte-arg"); 
   }  
   public static void main(String []args)
   { 
      HelloWorld n=new HelloWorld(); 
      n.m1(12); 
   } 
}
```

O/P: int-arg

**Question:**  12 is int type and byte type too. so in this case int is the exact match everytime. so what value should I provide if I want to call m1(byte) method? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either declare it with type or cast it

```
byte b = 12;
n.m1(b);
```

or cast

```
 n.m1((byte)b);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you will need to cast it.

In Java, plain numbers (ex: 12) are int by default, if the number has decimals (ex: 12.0), it will default to <strike>float</strike> double type (thank you @Sushil for the correction). There are suffixed to force some types, but not for all types (ex: 12L is long, 12.0f is float).

Comment: if the number has decimals (ex: 12.0), it will have default **double** type not float type.@simon

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cast prior to passing the value.

```
n.m1((byte)12);
```